# Serve non-HTML content with Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

Is it possible to return non-HTML content (JSON, CSV, etc.) with a Google Apps Script `doGet` function? I think that this might not be possible because not only does the function return the specified HTML, but also scripts to run the `google.run` commands and an iframe sandbox container that actually contains the served file. Can I put other text data in the served `index.html` and make it serve *only* the content in `index.html`?

Comment: Content service is made for that , have you read this ? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/content/

Comment: I've tried that. I copied the xkcd feed example and deployed as a web application. When I pasted the URL in my feed reader, it returned an error. I navigated to the web app and got a button to authorize the project to make external requests. Then it loaded and redirected me yet again to the actual RSS feed XML. When I tried to paste the URL of the page I ended up at, still no cigar. When I paste it in an a browser that has not loaded the app yet, I get the Google Drive login. Seems to me that no matter what I set my permissions, it won't work.

Comment: @Sergeinsas Never mind. It was just a problem with the publishing settings.

Answer (score 0):

As @Sergeinas suggested,I took a look at the Content Service. It worked. This was a stupid question.